# Does Oracle Applications API expose Web Services? (i.e. WS-* SOAP Web Services?)

Tags: web-services, oracle, soap, integration

I see Oracle has a comprehensive Integration Repository online (http://irep.oracle.com/).

Question is... how can one call these procedures? Do I have to do it through PL/SQL? Or do all these functions/procedures have corresponding web services exposed automatically?

Comment: What does .Net have to do with web services?  Or -- put another way -- all web services can always be called from .Net, so why is that in question?

Comment: Good point, suppose SOAP web services is more accurate. Will edit the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle is moving to SOA big time with tools and infrastructure support for BPEL, WebServices and ESB. Some parts of Oracle EBS already have web services api, others will surely follow in the future.

Here's some documentation on how to integrate peoplesoft crm with oracle ebs: http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/bpel_cookbook/pravin.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From your response I gather that only some, not all, API functions are exposed as web services.

Do you know if it is possible to call all the API functions/procedures using ODP.NET?  (I'm worried about 'Concurrent Programs' and 'Open Interface Tables', not sure what they are).

Comment: Concurrent manager (oracle's batch scheduler) has a plsql api, so you should be able to use it from odp.net.